# The temporary upload location is not valid

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I'm developing a web app with Java and Spring MVC (and hibernate to link to a MySQL database). I tried numerous ways to get my application to upload files. Unfortunately, I've encountered an error that says **my temporary upload location is not valid**. As a workaround, I've tried several locations like

- C:\Temp\
- C:\temp\
- C:/temp/
- /WEB-INF/tmp
- C:\Users\Default\AppData
- etc

Here is the error I'm getting

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: The temporary upload location [C:\Users\take\eclipse\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.4.RELEASE\base-instance\work\Catalina\localhost\ToolManagementSystem\WEB-INF\tmp] is not valid
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1073)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:912)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:279)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The temporary upload location [C:\Users\take\eclipse\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.4.RELEASE\base-instance\work\Catalina\localhost\ToolManagementSystem\WEB-INF\tmp] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2751)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2685)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:84)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

And here are my initializer and the configuration:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

private static final String LOCATION = "/WEB-INF/tmp";
private static final int MAX_FILE_SIZE = 2097152;
private static final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 2097152;
private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0;

public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(MvcConfiguration.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
}

public MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement(){
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(LOCATION, MAX_FILE_SIZE, MAX_REQUEST_SIZE, FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
    return multipartConfigElement;
  }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "...*")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:views.properties")
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";



@Resource
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

private Properties hibProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean(name="multipartResolver")
public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver(){
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver1() {
    ResourceBundleViewResolver resolver = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    resolver.setBasename("views");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver2() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setOrder(2);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

* holds base package name

Comment: Break the problem down - try adding a tmp to C:\Users\take\eclipse\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.4.RELEASE\base-instance\work\Catalina\localhost\ToolManagementSystem\WEB-INF\tmp - then the next problem is to change the location if required

Comment: I have a tmp folder under the WEB-INF folder, is that what you are revering to?

Comment: If you are on CentOS or RedHat, be sure you are not hit by https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5009 (It removes the default tmp directory used by the embedded tomcat after a while)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a directory /tmp under -

> C:\Users\take\eclipse\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.4.RELEASE\base-‌​instance\work\Catalina\localhost\ToolManagementSystem\WEB-INF

So you have a directory -

> C:\Users\take\eclipse\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.4.RELEASE\base-‌​instance\work\Catalina\localhost\ToolManagementSystem\WEB-INF\tmp

The other option is to change the temp directory through your tomcat configuration, or you can use spring boot which can configure this through an application property

Thanks

Comment: re: Spring boot. it might improve the answer if you named the application property

Comment: The property name in springboot is: 
multipart.location. 
You can set this property in your application.yml.
Other than that you can also set this props also:  
multipart.enabled, 
multipart.file-size-threshold, 
multipart.max-file-size, 
multipart.max-request-size

Comment: spring.servlet.multipart.location= # Intermediate location of uploaded files.

Comment: Shouldn't it be spring.http.multipart.location?

Comment: @farrellmr I have the same issue and im using intellij. your answer seems to be for sts/eclipse. can you tell same thing for intellij. im not able to find the similar path.

Comment: @Defozo spring.http.multipart.location is now deprecated. Instead of that use  spring.servlet.multipart.location

Answer (score 3):

For one of our environment it was happen when external process clean up temporary directory. So we solved it just with restarting application.

Comment: Restarting the complete application is not a solution to the problem in most situations.

Comment: @andred I really apologize but I have never said that restarting is a silver bullet for any use cases. I've just described situation that we faced with and provided solution for particular case.