# Could not parse multipart servlet request

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I tried to download file with my code, I have this error :

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse
>   multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException:
>   The temporary upload location
>   [/tmp/tomcat.5139949927832460132.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT] is
>   not valid

I did not understand how this can be do. 
I try to create the directory but same way. 
I try to reboot the VM bue same way.

I have this in the log :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: The temporary upload location [/tmp/tomcat.5139949927832460132.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT] is not valid
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
root cause

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: The temporary upload location [/tmp/tomcat.5139949927832460132.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT] is not valid
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:111)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1099)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
root cause

java.io.IOException: The temporary upload location [/tmp/tomcat.5139949927832460132.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT] is not valid
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2776)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3176)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1110)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Can you help me please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: is the location valid? /tmp/tomcat.5139949927832460132.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT

Comment: Yes ! I recreated manually the directory with the good right but i still have the error... :/

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38850504/3892213

Answer (score 2):

> You can specify override the /tmp folder by modifying the start.sh
>   script:
>
> JVM_OPTIONS="-Xrs -Xms256m -Xmx512m
>   -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tridion/deployer-live/tmp" The first three options (-Xrs -Xms256m -Xmx512m) are out of the box, I just added
>   '-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tridion/deployer-live/tmp'.
>
> The tomcat home folder and docbase folder are now created in the
>   location that I specified, and the cleanup script can no longer do any
>   harm.

source https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/14325

credits @Quirijn

Comment: I put the -Djava.io.tmpdir like you say. I obtain the same error ! :'(

Comment: what is the new error? are you getting error for new location or for the same location?

Comment: The same error !  It's the same location. 
But Without explication, we don't have the error now.  I don't know why...

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? uploading a file or downloading a file?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to specify custom directory path for temp storage through spring (or server) configuration.

But quick hack would be to create the mentioned directory and provide the read/write permissions as

```
mkdir -p /tmp/tomcat.5139949927832460132.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT

chmod 755 /tmp/tomcat.5139949927832460132.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT
```

> tomcat.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx - This will be different on each server.
>   Use this directory name from your server error.